# animate a button from left to right in a parent with text align center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two `buttons` which are centered with a text align center imposed on the parent element. The right button will at some point be faded out with `.fadeOut()`.

After the fadeOut occurs, the left element is placed in the center . However there is no animation . I added a css transition of `all 0.3s ease-in-out` on the left element but it still doesn't work because the  styling of the left element isn't really changing.

Any ideas to how to do it with my current styling ?

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5Ght/) of my current situation.

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-btn one">button 1</div>
    <div class="nav-btn two">button 2</div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.nav-btn.two').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.nav
{
    width : 100%;
    text-align : center;     
}
.nav-btn
{
    display : inline-block;
    padding : 10px;
    background : #252525;
    color : #fff;
}
```

I want to animate the left button to the center rather than just move it to align to center.

Comment: share your code or a fiddle.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I have editted my question to contain a jsfiddle

Comment: Why did I get so many down votes? I know this might seem trivial to some but I think its a valid question.

Comment: @user2678538 Questions are never downvoted for being trivial. They are downvoted for being unclear or showing no effort to solve autonomously. Also, code should always be placed in the question in case jsFiddle goes down.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OK agreed. But while it might seem that I made no effort, not having a jsfiddle doesn't necessarily mean that effort is non existing. I am sincerely lost on how to do this whilst keeping the   `text-align` property set to `center`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible with CSS. The disappearing button is switching from display (whatever) to `display:none". As such, the browser redraws the screen as though the second button was not there. Hence there is nothing to transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this kind of DOM manipulation can't trigger an animation at all. From what you're describing you should not use .fadeOut(), but instead try using an animation that reduces the width of that element. Don't forget to eliminate margins (use wrapping elements and padding instead) as well the padding on the target element (otherwise width animation to 0 will not do well).

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'overflow': 'hidden',
    }).animate({
        'width': 0
    }, 350, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

If you don't like this approach you probably have to redesign your buttons with absolute positioning.

Comment: This is a good solution and a very valid workaround! Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle to give the animation for moving the button to center.

Code Snippet:

```
$('.nav-btn.two').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $('.nav-btn.one').animate({'margin-left':'+=90px'
     });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/V5Ght/19/)